# Transform JSON Data of one column from excel csv in Azure data factory

Tags: json, excel, csv, azure-data-factory

Have an excel csv as a source in that one particular entity (500)  contains JSON formatted data with hierarchy like below

```json
500 7   30600052764 30128903357 {"type": "reportingData", "merStoreId": "0099703", "productData": [{"productCode": "107", "totalAmount": "47.92", "quantity": "1.000", "unitPrice": "47.92", "tax1Amount": "0.00"},{"productCode": "963", "totalAmount": "2.40", "quantity": "1.000", "unitPrice": "2.40", "tax1Amount": "0.00"}, {"productCode": "913", "totalAmount": "20.00", "quantity": "1.000", "unitPrice": "20.00", "tax1Amount": "0.00"}]}
```

Has to convert this data in excel csv to my sink in meaningful format , can any one help me

Comment: What would be a "meaningful format"? If you don't provide the expected result then no one can answer your question. Also, is that line of data supposed to represent the content of a CSV file? Which command did you use for getting it?

Comment: it should convert into excel csv format like column and rows

Comment: Your JSON is 2D so you can't represent it in a 1D format like CSV, unless you make a few choices, which is why I ask of you to edit your question and add a table that shows the expected result of the conversion.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

To unroll the Json column as you want you can follow below steps in Data flow activity:

- Sample data at source
  [image]
- As it is taking the Json column as string first, I took Parse transformation and unfold the Json. In parse setting select **Document form as `single document` and column as name of column you want to give Expression as column you want to unfold and expression as**

```
(type as string,        merStoreId as integer,      productData as string[])
```

[image]
**Data preview:**
[image]

- After that create derived column transformation and create column with the respective value of column unfolded in previous transformation
  [image]
  **Data preview:**
  [image]

-As you have one object with array in Json column to unfold that take flatten transformation and flattern that array column. [image]

- Now, unfold that array Json in another parse transformation parse setting select **Document form as `single document` and column as name of column you want to give Expression as column you want to unfold and expression as**

```
(productCode as integer,        totalAmount as double,      quantity as double,     unitPrice as double,        tax1Amount as double)
```

[image]
**Data preview:**
[image]

- After that create derived column transformation and create column with the respective value of column unfolded in previous transformation
  [image]
  **Data preview:**
  [image]
- Now take union transformation after derived column 1 and with derived column 2
  [image]
  **Data preview:**
  [image]
- now take select transformation and select the columns and store the columns into the sink.
  [image]